# PartitionLostEvent when starting Coherence cluster

Tags: java, oracle-coherence

I have a Coherence cluster with 5 physical machines and 3 JVMs per machine. Upon startup, I get PartitionLostEvent from one of the nodes. This is the output from the node that gives the event:

```
    18 Feb 2014 14:05:02,570 [Logger@9232314 3.5.3/465p5] INFO  Coherence  - 3.5.3/465p5 (thread=DefaultCacheServer, member=2): Started DefaultCacheServer...    

SafeCluster: Name=tmsngCluster
WellKnownAddressList(Size=5,
  WKA{Address=172.17.0.205, Port=4044}
  WKA{Address=172.17.0.202, Port=4044}
  WKA{Address=172.17.0.203, Port=4044}
  WKA{Address=172.17.0.201, Port=4044}
  WKA{Address=172.17.0.204, Port=4044}
  )

MasterMemberSet
  (
  ThisMember=Member(Id=2, Timestamp=2014-02-18 14:05:00.396, Address=172.17.0.205:4044, MachineId=51999, Location=machine:nec05,process:28959,member:INPUT1, Role=Input)
  OldestMember=Member(Id=1, Timestamp=2014-02-18 14:04:30.049, Address=172.17.0.201:4044, MachineId=3867, Location=machine:nec01,process:11301,member:PROCESS1, Role=Process)
  ActualMemberSet=MemberSet(Size=11, BitSetCount=2
    Member(Id=1, Timestamp=2014-02-18 14:04:30.049, Address=172.17.0.201:4044, MachineId=3867, Location=machine:nec01,process:11301,member:PROCESS1, Role=Process)
    Member(Id=2, Timestamp=2014-02-18 14:05:00.396, Address=172.17.0.205:4044, MachineId=51999, Location=machine:nec05,process:28959,member:INPUT1, Role=Input)
    Member(Id=3, Timestamp=2014-02-18 14:05:00.415, Address=172.17.0.204:4045, MachineId=23582, Location=machine:nec04,process:32568,member:PROCESS1, Role=Process)
    Member(Id=4, Timestamp=2014-02-18 14:05:00.417, Address=172.17.0.204:4046, MachineId=23582, Location=machine:nec04,process:32648,member:CLIENT1, Role=Output)
    Member(Id=5, Timestamp=2014-02-18 14:05:00.414, Address=172.17.0.203:4044, MachineId=60701, Location=machine:nec03,process:32077,member:INPUT1, Role=Input)
    Member(Id=6, Timestamp=2014-02-18 14:05:00.441, Address=172.17.0.203:4045, MachineId=60701, Location=machine:nec03,process:32040,member:PROCESS1, Role=Process)
    Member(Id=7, Timestamp=2014-02-18 14:05:00.451, Address=172.17.0.205:4045, MachineId=51999, Location=machine:nec05,process:28928,member:PROCESS1, Role=Process)
    Member(Id=8, Timestamp=2014-02-18 14:05:00.47, Address=172.17.0.204:4044, MachineId=23582, Location=machine:nec04,process:32605,member:INPUT1, Role=Input)
    Member(Id=9, Timestamp=2014-02-18 14:05:00.53, Address=172.17.0.202:4044, MachineId=32284, Location=machine:nec02,process:1785,member:PROCESS1, Role=Process)
    Member(Id=10, Timestamp=2014-02-18 14:05:00.551, Address=172.17.0.203:4046, MachineId=60701, Location=machine:nec03,process:32120,member:CLIENT1, Role=Output)
    Member(Id=11, Timestamp=2014-02-18 14:05:00.568, Address=172.17.0.205:4046, MachineId=51999, Location=machine:nec05,process:28996,member:CLIENT1, Role=Output)
    )
  RecycleMillis=240000
  RecycleSet=MemberSet(Size=0, BitSetCount=0
    )
  )

Services
  (
  TcpRing{TcpSocketAccepter{State=STATE_OPEN, ServerSocket=172.17.0.205:4044}, Connections=[1]}
  ClusterService{Name=Cluster, State=(SERVICE_STARTED, STATE_JOINED), Id=0, Version=3.5, OldestMemberId=1}
  InvocationService{Name=Management, State=(SERVICE_STARTED), Id=1, Version=3.1, OldestMemberId=1}
  DistributedCache{Name=BackService, State=(SERVICE_STARTED), LocalStorage=enabled, PartitionCount=1021, BackupCount=1, AssignedPartitions=0, BackupPartitions=0}
  DistributedCache{Name=InputBackService, State=(SERVICE_STARTED), LocalStorage=enabled, PartitionCount=1021, BackupCount=1, AssignedPartitions=770, BackupPartitions=0}
  ReplicatedCache{Name=ReplicatedCache, State=(SERVICE_STARTED), Id=7, Version=3.0, OldestMemberId=1}
  InvocationService{Name=DefaultInvocationService, State=(SERVICE_STARTED), Id=15, Version=3.1, OldestMemberId=2}
  )

18 Feb 2014 14:05:02,604 [Logger@9232314 3.5.3/465p5] WARN  Coherence  - 3.5.3/465p5 (thread=DistributedCache:InputBackService, member=2): Assigned 1021 orphaned primary partitions
18 Feb 2014 14:05:02,654 [DistributedCache:BackService:EventDispatcher] INFO  server.common.watchdog.MemberLeftListener  - Member joined: Member(Id=9, Timestamp=2014-02-18 14:05:00.53, Address=172.17.0.202:4044, MachineId=32284, Location=machine:nec02,process:1785,member:PROCESS1, Role=Process)
18 Feb 2014 14:05:02,655 [DistributedCache:BackService:EventDispatcher] INFO  server.common.master.MasterServiceImpl  - Member joined: Member(Id=9, Timestamp=2014-02-18 14:05:00.53, Address=172.17.0.202:4044, MachineId=32284, Location=machine:nec02,process:1785,member:PROCESS1, Role=Process)
18 Feb 2014 14:05:02,657 [Environment.Background.Executor:Thread-2] ERROR server.common.watchdog.LostPartitionsEventProcessor  - Partitions are lost for DistributedCache{Name=InputBackService, State=(SERVICE_STARTED), LocalStorage=enabled, PartitionCount=1021, BackupCount=1, AssignedPartitions=1021, BackupPartitions=0}
```

I am using Coherence 3.5.3 (patch5).

This is the configuration of the service:

```
<distributed-scheme>
        <scheme-name>inputDistributedScheme</scheme-name>
        <service-name>InputBackService</service-name>
        <backing-map-scheme>
            <local-scheme>
                <service-name>InputBackLocalService</service-name>
            </local-scheme>
        </backing-map-scheme>
        <partition-listener>
            <class-name>com.company.tmsng.server.common.watchdog.LostPartitionListener</class-name>
        </partition-listener>
        <local-storage system-property="tangosol.coherence.inputNode">false</local-storage>
        <autostart system-property="tangosol.coherence.inputNode">false</autostart>
    </distributed-scheme>
```

Why do I get this event when the cluster is still starting?

Answer (score 0):

Remember a similar issue. In our case the problem was a mismatch jar versions between the machines (physical) since we loaded a customized jar containing own implementation for CachePersistency and entry processors.
Check your versions and even MD5 or hash values if you have such files (custom) loaded.

Comment: Versions are the same, this is not it.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest (if at all possible) upgrading to a more recent version; 3.5 is getting pretty ancient at this point! (The current version is 12.1.2.)

Second, it appears that the partitions aren't being lost from the message shown, but rather that the server is claiming them (because no other server owns them). That is the thing to figure out. I've never seen this behavior, but it could be indicative of some form of communication error; I'd check the logs on all servers to verify.